# How to list students for every course in knockout and durandal in SPA

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, durandal-2.0

Here is my class :

```
public class Course : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public virtual int? TeacherId { get; set; }
        public virtual Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<CourseStudent> CourseStudents { get; set; } 
    }
}, 
 public class CourseStudent : BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual int CourseId { get; set; }
        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
        public virtual int StudentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I defined COurse in Breeze Controler and this is show on my view, the name of course, teacher and Description but hot to show students for specific course.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "property path expand" query technique to eager load the each course's students:

http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples#PropertyPathExpand

the html/knockout bindings would look something like this:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: courses">
   <li>
      <h1 data-bind="text: Name" />

      <ul data-bind="foreach: CourseStudents">
         <li data-bind="text: Student.Name" />
      </ul>   
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: [meta]i tried to expand but it doesn't work i'm doing something wrong here but i don't now what- this is my query in :  var query = EntityQuery.from('Courses')
                .expand('Teacher','CourseStudent')
                .orderBy('name');

Comment: missing 's':  `.expand('Teacher', 'CourseStudent**s**')`

Comment: I've fixed this but it show "Unable to parse binding, refernece error", Here is my html :  <div  data-bind="with: course"> <div >
  Name:  <span data-bind="text : name"></span> 
        </div?
  <div data-bind="with:teacher">
        Name of teacher:  <span data-bind="text : name"></span>
            </div>
         <div data-bind="with:coursestudents" class="alert alert-danger">
  List of Students :<span data-bind="text:student.name"></span>
 </div>          
 </div> And i use FOREACH also show the same error

Comment: And i really need help for this... pls help me

Comment: I think there are two issues:
1) improper capitalization in the bindings- for example `with: teacher` should be `with: Teacher` because the Course entity's 'Teacher' property name is capitalized.  Same thing with the course name and student name bindings, etc.
2) I don't think the `text: Student.Name` binding will work unless you change the expand call in your query to `.expand('Teacher', 'CourseStudents.Student')`

Comment: No i use CamelCase and everything is show on a view the only problem is to show Students who learning in one course, i've fixed 'CourseStudents.Student' but again it's show the error in binding coursestudent.

Comment: camel case for the CourseStudents property would be 'courseStudents' (capitalize the s in student).

Comment: try `<div data-bind="foreach: courseStudents"><span data-bind="text: student.name" /></div>`

Comment: bummer.  I can't move this discussion to a chat because your rep is below 20.  What is the output of `JSON.stringify(course)` ?